# how to add multiple variations of long condition in a single strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

as you can see I have here two variations of long condition in a single strategy

//sqzmom and //variationone

and as you can see I have duplicated the whole thing and changed variables a bit in order to make that variation, it is working fine but I want to know if there's a more efficient way to achieve this? when for example I want to add more variations, because duplicating the whole thing over and over will get very hard to manage.
thanks in advance

```
//sqzmom
length = input(10, title='BB Length ')
mult = input(3.2, title='BB MultFactor ')
lengthKC = input(20, title='KC Length ')
multKC = input(1.8, title='KC MultFactor ')

useTrueRange = input(true, title='Use TrueRange (KC)')

//FILTERS
useExtremeOrders = input(false, title='Early entry on momentum change')
useMomAverage = input(false, title='Filter for Momenutum value')
MomentumMin = input(20, title='Min for momentum')

// Calculate BB
src = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", close)
basis = ta.sma(src, length)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(src, length)
upperBB = basis + dev
lowerBB = basis - dev

// Calculate KC
ma = ta.sma(src, lengthKC)
range_1 = useTrueRange ? ta.tr : high - low
rangema = ta.sma(range_1, lengthKC)
upperKC = ma + rangema * multKC
lowerKC = ma - rangema * multKC

sqzOn = lowerBB > lowerKC and upperBB < upperKC
sqzOff = lowerBB < lowerKC and upperBB > upperKC
noSqz = sqzOn == false and sqzOff == false

val = ta.linreg(src - math.avg(math.avg(ta.highest(high, lengthKC), ta.lowest(low, lengthKC)), ta.sma(close, lengthKC)), lengthKC, 0)

iff_1 = val > nz(val[1]) ? color.lime : color.green
iff_2 = val < nz(val[1]) ? color.red : color.maroon
bcolor = val > 0 ? iff_1 : iff_2
scolor = noSqz ? color.blue : sqzOn ? color.black : color.aqua
plot(val, color=bcolor, style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=4)
plot(0, color=scolor, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=2)

//LOGIC
//momentum filter
filterMom = useMomAverage ? math.abs(val) > MomentumMin / 100000 ? true : false : true

//standard condition
longCondition = scolor == color.aqua and bcolor == color.lime and filterMom
//sqzmom


//variationone
lengthone = input(10, title='BB Length one')
multone = input(3.2, title='BB MultFactor one')
lengthKCone = input(20, title='KC Length one')
multKCone = input(1.8, title='KC MultFactor one')

useTrueRangeone = input(true, title='Use TrueRange (KC)')

//FILTERS
useExtremeOrdersone = input(false, title='Early entry on momentum change')
useMomAverageone = input(false, title='Filter for Momenutum valoneue')
MomentumMinone = input(20, title='Min for momentum')

// Calculate BB
basisone = ta.sma(src, lengthone)
devone = multone * ta.stdev(src, lengthone)
upperBBone = basisone + devone
lowerBBone = basisone - devone

// Calculate KC
maone = ta.sma(src, lengthKCone)
range_1one = useTrueRangeone ? ta.tr : high - low
rangemaone = ta.sma(range_1one, lengthKCone)
upperKCone = maone + rangemaone * multKCone
lowerKCone = maone - rangemaone * multKCone

sqzOnone = lowerBBone > lowerKCone and upperBBone < upperKCone
sqzOffone = lowerBBone < lowerKCone and upperBBone > upperKCone
noSqzone = sqzOnone == false and sqzOffone == false

valone = ta.linreg(src - math.avg(math.avg(ta.highest(high, lengthKCone), ta.lowest(low, lengthKCone)), ta.sma(close, lengthKCone)), lengthKCone, 0)

iff_1one = valone > nz(valone[1]) ? color.lime : color.green
iff_2one = valone < nz(valone[1]) ? color.red : color.maroon
bcolorone = valone > 0 ? iff_1one : iff_2one
scolorone = noSqzone ? color.blue : sqzOnone ? color.black : color.aqua
//plot(valone, color=bcolorone, style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=4)
//plot(0, color=scolorone, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=2)

//LOGIC
//momentum filter
filterMomone = useMomAverageone ? math.abs(valone) > MomentumMinone / 100000 ? true : false : true

//standard condition
longConditionone = scolorone == color.aqua and bcolorone == color.lime and filterMomone
//variationone
```